# Grouping Json Data by Value in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and any help will be appreciated.

I have a Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "key1": "truck",
        "key2": "car1",
        "key3": "motorcycle",
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "key1": "truck",
        "key2": "car2",
        "key3": "motorcycle",    
    },
    {
        "id": 1003,
        "key1": "truck",
        "key2": "car2",
        "key3": "motorcycle",    
    },
    {
        "id": 1004,
        "key1": "truck",
        "key2": "car2",
        "key3": "motorcycle",    
    },
    {
        "id": 1005,
        "key1": "truck",
        "key2": "car3",
        "key3": "motorcycle",    
    },
]
```

I can reach values like this:

```
VStack{    
    ForEach(userData.vehicles) { vehicle in
       Text(vehicle.key2)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
car1
car2
car2
car2
car3
```

What I want to see is:

```
car1
car2
car3
```

Is there any way to group the keys in SwiftUI?

Edit:
@MahdiBM requested the following codes in comment section.

Vehicle declaration

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false
    @Published var vehicles = vehicleInfo
}
```

Reading Json

```
let vehicleInfo: [Vehicle] = readJSON("vehicleInfo.json")
func readJSON<T: Codable>(_ named: String) -> T {
    if let resPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath {
        do {
            let dirContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: resPath)
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            let filteredFiles = dirContents.filter{ $0.contains(".json")}
            for fileName in filteredFiles {
                if let documentsURL = documentsURL {
                    let sourceURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    let destURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
                        print("Save to documents")
                    } catch {
                        print("ERROR FileManager.default.copyItem:: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch { print("ERRIR 2", error) }
    }
    
    let data: Data
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("vehicleInfo.json")
        
        data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let foo = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
//        print(foo)
        
        return foo
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't find  in main bundle.")
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

```
struct Vehicle: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var key1: String
    var key2: String
    var key3: String
}
```

---

*SO says; "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."*

They need to review this requirement I believe, because there is nothing I can say more.

Comment: How does vehicle declaration look like? How do you turn the json into vehicles?

Comment: I added that to my question.

Comment: thanks, i need to see Vehicle to be able to give you an appropriate answer. Something like `struct Vehicle { var key1: String ...... }`. This above code looks good though and at first glance doesn't have any real problems.

Comment: Thank you for trying to make my question clear. I also added that.

Comment: So you only want to access key2 from the struct? If not, in the json, do you consider all elements to be equal that has key2 = "Car2" even though the id is different for each?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I also want to access different keys and elements can be different for the object that has same key2 value.

Comment: Then you can't remove duplicates based on only one key.  For example if one vehicle has `key1` = "truck1" and `key2` = "car2" and another one had  `key1` = "truck2" and `key2` = "car2" then you want to see both I assume?

Comment: No actually. I want to show the user the unique values. When the user selects one of the unique value, I will show the user corresponding objects that has the chosen value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if im wrong but from what i understand you have some `Vehicles` that can have a repetitive `key2` and you don't like that. You instead want the `key2`s to not be repetitive.

```
var vehicles: [Vehicle] = [...]

// to group all `key2`s together, you can use `.map`:
var allKey2: [String] = vehicles.map { $0.key2 } // or `vehicles.map(\.key2)`, both are the same

// now you have all `key2`s grouped together
// to remove repetitive members, you can store the keys in a `Set` and convert them
// back to `Array`. why `Set`? because `Set` automatically removes repetitive members,
// but it also doesnt have any order for the members so we need to order the members back.
var noRepeatUnorderedAllKey2: [String] = Array(Set(allKey2))
// here we sort based on which member appeared sooner/later in the `allKey2` array
var noRepeatOrderedAllKey2: [String] = noRepeatUnorderedAllKey2.sorted {
    (allKey2.firstIndex(of: $0) ?? 0) < (allKey2.firstIndex(of: $1) ?? 0)
}
```

now you can do this, and you'll have `car1, car2, car3` instead of `car1, car2, car2, car2, car3`:

```
VStack{    
    ForEach(noRepeatOrderedAllKey2) { vehicleKey2 in
       Text(vehicleKey2)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right and thank you so much for your time. I got following error: `Cannot use instance member 'vehicles' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`. I initialized like this: `init() { vehicles = [] }` What could be the problem?

Comment: i need more context, where did you type that `init() { vehicles = [] }`? the error says you need to first set a value for all things in the struct before using any values of the struct, but i can't see why its saying that here.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, I solved with using `id: \.self` in ForEach. Your solution is top-notch, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a new property in your `UserData` class to hold the unique keys from your Vehicle array. This property is automatically updated when the `vehicles` property is set.

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false
    @Published var vehicles: [Vehicle] {
        willSet {
            vehicleKeys = Set(newValue.map(\.key2)).sorted()
        }
    }
    @Published var vehicleKeys: [String] = []
}
```

And then you can use the `vehicleKeys` array in your `ForEach` and you could have a function that returns the Vehicle objects for the selected key.

Another option is to use a dictionary, since then you would have easier access to the corresponding Vehicle objects for a key

```
    @Published var vehicles: [Vehicle] {
        willSet {
            vehicleKeys = Dictionary(grouping: newValue, by: \.key2)
        }
    }
    @Published var vehicleKeys: [String: [Vehicle]] = [:]
```

Dictionaries aren't sorted though

Comment: Thank you for your time. I got `Class 'UserData' has no initializers` error. How can I initialize it?

Comment: `init() { vehicles = [] }` is one way.

Comment: I did like this: `ForEach(userData.vehicleKeys, id: \.self) { vehicleKey in Text(vehicleKey)}` No data show up. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Is userData declared with property wrapper @ObservedObject?

Comment: I use `@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData`. I also tried `@ObservedObject` but some other view crashed with that. I believe `@EnvironmentObject` should work but no chance, no data show up.

Comment: Since userData.vehicle works for you it is surprising that userData.vehicleKeys doesn’t but this is all beside your original question which I have answered. Getting your UserData class to work properly is a different issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I couldn't make it work with your answer but another answer solved my problem.